# If you have multiple threads using runOnUiThread, are they different threads, or are they all running on one thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm new to multithreading, so excuse my potentially silly question.

I need to use several threads in my app. However, virtually all of these threads will modify the UI. I've successfully used runOnUiThread, but what I fear is that if I create different threads of the same type, they will all be running on one thread, the "Ui thread", which may slow down my app.

Is this true, or am I greatly misunderstanding?

My thread which I will essentially multiply:

```
private void goldPerSecondMethod() {

    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while (goldCount < 1000) {
                try {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            goldCount += 0.1f;
                            textGoldCount.setText(goldCount + " Gold");
                            textGoldCount.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

                        }
                    });
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> I need to use several threads in my app.

Why? For example, there is no need for a thread that you create yourself in the code sample you have above. Use a `postDelayed()` loop (no threads), or use `ScheduledExecutorService` (threads, but you don't have to create them) for timing.

> what I fear is that if I create different threads of the same type, they will all be running on one thread, the "Ui thread", which may slow down my app.

I have no idea what "the same type" means. In your code snippet above, everything in the `Runnable` that you pass to `runOnUiThread()` will be executed on the main application thread (sometimes called the UI thread). Everything else in your outermost `run()` will be executed on this background thread.

Comment: I'm looking into postDelayed and Handlers now :) But something that I don't understand - Is a Handler created in onCreate() still bound to the UI thread, or does it create an entirely new thread? Thank you again, buddy :)

Comment: @BipBapApps: "Is a Handler created in onCreate() still bound to the UI thread, or does it create an entirely new thread? " -- it is bound to the main application (UI) thread. If you want a `Handler` tied to another thread, use a `HandlerThread`.

Answer (score 0):

It is correct that you need to run UI updates on the UI thread. Hence you do `textGoldCount.setText(...)` on the UI thread. Technically, this is a correct approach.

However, it's unnecessary to call `setGravity(...)` every time you update the text field. You should be able to set the gravity once. Best place would be probably your XML view description.

At the end you don't do much heavy work on the UI thread, except updating the text view's text. As every thread is sleeping 1 second before updating the UI again, there should be no notable delay for the user as long as you don't run too many of those threads.